# Does firebase auth:import overwrites the existing list of auth users?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-cli

Upon using `firebase auth:import` does it overwrites the list of users which are already present or it just adds another auth user?
If it overwrites then what will happen if some user sign-ups just a moment before `firebase auth:import` takes place. Will the user data created in the mean-time gets lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user with given UID exists, then only properties that have changed will be updated. For example, if user with `UID 1234` is already present in Firebase with email `user1234@gmail.com` but the file being imported has different email then the email will be overwritten.